# Android : Scrolling is disabled?

Tags: javascript, android, html, android-layout

In my android application i used some html pages with various details, it can be viewed perfectly in browser(i.e- we can scroll up & down). But the same page can't have scrolling option in android and it can't move (i.e- it became static)

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: is there any scroll view in your activity if so then remove that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it on android version 2.2 or lower...well then scroll bar don't work in that version. For that you'll have to use a plugin like iscroll. check here http://cubiq.org/iscroll

I know its pathetic that a basic feature like scroll is not working but its a bug in adroid.